# libx264 for ffmpeg on linux

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I am running ffmpeg on ubuntu.

I tried to set the codec to libx264 but it was not recognised by ffmmpeg.

Is there a way too install that codec for use by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

If the codec lib isn't linked in your binary, you can get one which does from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ (get a git build).

Comment: It seems that installing the libavcodec-extra package might also solve the OP's issue. (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libavcodec-extra)

Answer (score 0):

Compile x264 by yourself, then compile ffmpeg with option `--enable-libx264`